# Bluetooth Battery Level API getBatteryLevel() is not working in Android 8.1.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-source, batterymanager

I am trying to get the Battery Level from `BluetoothDevice` in Android 8.1.0 of remotely connected BT device.

```
BluetoothDevice mBTDevice = (BluetoothDevice) bundle
                        .getParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
int val = mBtDevice.getBatteryLevel();
```

But its `val` always returning  value as "-1" . It seems not working in Android 8.1.0

Got the info from this [link](https://www.xda-developers.com/bluetooth-battery-level-indicators-android/)

Comment: From your link, "(or -1 if Bluetooth is disabled, the device is disconnected, or does not support reporting its battery level)"

Comment: Not all devices support this.  What device are you connected to?